# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access

Tags: javascript, cordova, magento, ionic-framework, cors

Hi guys i am working on an ionic app for magento and i am beginner in ionic also i am using google chrome browser but when i run this app in browser using 
`ionic serve` command app is running but its empty i am getting this error in console

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I have search a lot found a solution to use this extension
[Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en)

when i use this extension error is fixed but still app is empty data is not showing in browser but when i am runing this app on **PhoneGap** or in device its working fine and fetching all data from magento.
i don't have server access where this magento website is installed..

Comment: Did you try setting the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on your *server* rather than with weird browser extensions?

Comment: i don't have server access can i test this app with local server as well..? i have magento in my localhost can i test it on localhost as well..?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Google chrome there is a plugin that you can add :
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

It had solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you need to setup/unable CORS on the magneto sever. You can try setup a proxy for ionic serve - take a look here: http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/

Inside your .project file:

```
{
  "name": "proxy-example",
  "app_id": "",
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/api",
      "proxyUrl": "http://mad.xs4arabia.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

so in the your services/controllers:

```
$http.get('/api/myendpoint')
```

which would resolve to:

```
http://mad.xs4arabia.com/myendpoint
```

Comment: my path is mad.xs4arabia.com and my app code is defand1 how can i put this url in proxies

Comment: Update the answer. Take a read through that link and make sure you understand the concept, its something you will always have to deal it ;-)

Comment: thanks dude i will check this but what's this /api ..?

Comment: {
  "name": "MageApp",
  "app_id": ""
}
this is in my .project file do i need to replace this or put your code below this ??

Comment: i have replace this but still getting error 
. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.